# What does same scheme account mean in banking purpose?

Tags: savings, bank-account, online-banking, nepal

I'm planning to open an online savings account in a bank where i already have normal savings account. In the form though it asks me to declare that i don't have same scheme account in their bank. I'm not sure what this means, and is normal savings supposed to be same schemed account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I could find, it looks as though a "scheme account" is one used for specialized savings and investment.  Here's a link to a PDF from the Nepal Stock Exchange that discusses various types of scheme accounts:

http://www.nepalstock.com/uploads/files/company/0e5687cca988da721eb1852ec22b1f4d.pdf

Hope this is what you're looking for.  Good luck!